# List View (index controller) does not update after an individual record has been edited

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, caching

I have an MVC app with multiple controllers reading/writing to/from MS SQL database, and I want to consolidate all database calls to one controller (called XYZdataset.cs) instead of making calls to the DB from individual methods in each controller.

The situation is: when I edit an individual record, upon successful database update, I'm redirected to the Index() method where the list of all records is displayed.

With Scenario 1 (below), the Index() view displays the updated list, with all freshly updated values.

With Scenario 2, the Index() view does NOT display the freshly updated values; however, when I go to the record that I just edited, I see the newest values - so, the database gets updated.

What could be the culprit?  I have tried using both [OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
and [OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)] on the controller and method level, but it does not change the outcome.

Thanks for any hints on where to look for solution!

```
/*** Items CONTROLLER ***/
    // SCENARIO 1 - works like a charm, displays updated list in the view after a record has been updated:
public ActionResult Index()
    {
    var itemList = db.EntityObj.Include(i => i.Status).OrderByDescending(i => i.itemId);

      return View(itemList.ToList());
    }


    // Scenario 2 - does not display the freshly made record edits, even though the changes are recorded in the DB: 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    var itemList = XYZdataset.GetList("a");

      return View(itemList.ToList());
    }


namespace APPspace.DAL
{
public class XYZdataset
{

    private static MVCTestsDBEntities db = new MVCTestsDBEntities();

    public static List<ItemXYZ> GetList(string viewType)
    {
        List<ItemXYZ> itemList = new List<ItemXYZ>();

        switch (viewType.ToLower())
            {
            case "p": 
                itemList = db.EntityObj.Include(i => i.Status).Where(i=>i.statusId == 999).OrderByDescending(i => i.itemId);
                break;
            case "a": 
                itemList = db.EntityObj.Include(i => i.Status).OrderByDescending(i => i.itemId);
                break;
            default:
                itemList = db.EntityObj.Include(i => i.Status).Where(i=>i.statusId == 999).OrderByDescending(i => i.itemId);
                break;
            }

        return itemList;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Finally figured it out - the culprit is the static var declaration in the method calls inside the XYZdataset class.  I created a private class-wide static variable for initiating the dataset class calls (private XYZdataset ds = new XYZdataset(); ), removed all "static" from the XYZdataset method return params, and then referenced ds.[method_name] for retrieving the necessary datasets, and voila!  Life is good again.